# Sample clothing database schema. (What am I doing wrong?)

Tags: php, mysql

So here are my tables for a sample clothing database:

Table **Product**:

```
ID | Title | Description
--------------------------------
1  | Shirt | Man's Shirt
2  | Dress | The one that I like
```

Table **Product_Info**:

```
PI_ID | PI_Color | PI_Size | PI_Quantity | PI_Price | PI_RetailPrice
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | Blue     | Small   | 3           | 65.00    | 75.00
1     | Yellow   | Medium  | 1           | 55.00    | 60.00
1     | Yellow   | Large   | 2           | 55.00    | 60.00
2     | White    | Large   | 5           | 125.00   | 150.00
```

So now this is all good but when it comes to displaying it I am having trouble. I want to display all data in a table for administrators to quickly search/edit/delete or add products. How can I display this so that all product details are within 1 row, so goal display should be something like:

```
Title | Description | Color | Size  | Price
--------------------------------------------------------
Shirt | Man's Shirt | Blue  | Small | 65.00
                      Yellow| Medium| 55.00
                              Large | 55.00
```

How can I display this with PHP/HTML so that its readable and easy to understand. Do I need to change the way I structured tables? I am not asking for a code I just need an idea on how to display this in an easy way.

Comment: The structure seems good (as far as you problem is concerned). You should not change it just to simplify a view. You want a complex view, then that needs to be sophisticated. Keep the tables clean and simple. In this case you will have to execute subqueries to populate some of the cells in the html table... but the db is ok.

Comment: @Frazz thank you. I guess I will play around with html to display this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have an easy and nice way to edit/read the table, you have to make some HTML/PHP.

You have to write in your back end some PHP to get the data from the DB. You need a `JOIN` request:

```
SELECT * FROM Product p JOIN Product_Info pi ON p.ID=pi.PI_ID
```

This will get you something like this (with all the columns of your two tables, that I haven't represented).

```
 ID | Title | Description | PI_ID | Color | Size  | Price
 --------------------------------------------------------
 1  | Shirt | Man's Shirt |  1    | Blue  | Small | 65.00
 1  | Shirt | Man's Shirt |  1    | Yellow| Medium| 55.00
 1  | Shirt | Man's Shirt |  1    | Yellow| Large | 55.00
 2  | Dress | The one ... |  2    | White | Large | 125.00
```

Then in your HTML front end you need to make a loop to display this information as you want, add and edit button where you want to edit

Then your front end will send the edited data to your back end which will make the `UPDATE`request accordingly.

Comment: You can use rowspan to to union some cells. You have to loop through the results a bit before building the tablerows, and use some variables to do it right. It's tricky, but it can be done. But this is the right place to do it... in the front-end, not in the back-end.